# Python concatenate multiple unicode string and variables

Tags: python, encoding

This line is working fine in my code:

```
wikipedia = MediaWiki(url=u'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',user_agent='pyMediaWiki-User-Agent-String')
```

but this one is not:

```
language='en'
wikipedia = MediaWiki(url=u'https://'+language+u'.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',user_agent='pyMediaWiki-User-Agent-String')
```

it's giving me `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`

I guess the problem is with the string encoding or concatenation, I tried different ways to encode but couldn't find the right syntax.

What would be the right syntax for this? I'm using Python 2

Comment: I think this `+language+u` causes the problem. `u` is not a string

Comment: Are you using a 2.x python? If not, delete the `u` character before quotation mark

Comment: Take a look there: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Could you please post the complete stacktrace since the error type points towards a simple typo (imho) ... because a get request against the url did only give me a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError once i intentionally mispelled the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try string formating,

OLD Formating:

```
language='en'
_url = u'https://%s.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'%language
wikipedia = MediaWiki(url=_url,user_agent='pyMediaWiki-User-Agent-String')
```

NEW Formating:

```
language='en'
_url = u'https://{}.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'.format(language)
wikipedia = MediaWiki(url=_url,user_agent='pyMediaWiki-User-Agent-String')
```